# Optimizing SQL query generated with Extbase

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I am doing a query on several tables with lots of records. In a specific one the relation is m:n and the generated query JOINs the appropriate tables. The problem is the resulting query is extremely slow. I was able to rewrite it by taking out the JOINs and putting it in a sub query which did the trick but I am not sure how to add it in the repository where I create the query. Basically what I want is to still use createQuery() since it does a lot of checks but to optimize only a small part from it.

Is it possible with the current implementation or is my only option to write the entire query from scratch?

Comment: Maybe you can speed up the join-query by adding some keys to the tables? Try to add keys for the columns which on which the query joins.

Comment: I've already added all needed keys. The problem is how the query is generated. I've managed to change it with contains() instead of equals() but when I also add ordering columns it goes back to the same slow speed.

Comment: Have you tried to add keys for the ordering columns? If that does not help, I have no more ideas, but maybe someone else has.

Comment: Yes, the problem is not indexing but the way the query searches for data in different tables. If I could add a simple custom statement in the constraints it will work but so far I couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a manual query that is optimized:

```
$query = $this->createquery();
$query->getQuerySettings()->setRespectStoragePage(FALSE);
$query->statement('your query'); 
return $query->execute(TRUE);
```

As long as the query still returns records from the table that belongs to the repository (and children of the model), Extbase will still do the mapping you need to have Fluid access to the object, its children and their properties.

Comment: setReturnRawQueryResult(TRUE) is deprecated in TYPO3 6.2 - To get the same functionality, use query->execute(TRUE); and remove setReturnRawQueryResult.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it in the description.